# Why Session details are not accessible inside php namespace

Tags: php, session, namespaces

I have developing a basic session handler class. The issue is when ever I am setting session into any controller action, same session details are not accessible in other action/controller. It displays me empty array. Entire system is php namespace oriented.

Reference: [Session Manager](https://github.com/cygnite/framework/blob/master/src/Cygnite/Common/SessionManager/Session.php)

We do save and retrieve session as below.

```
use Cygnite\Common\SessionManager\Session;
use Cygnite\Common\Encrypt;                                    
$session = new Session(new Encrypt); 
$session->save($key, $value); 
$userDetails = $session->get($key); 

var_dump($userDetails);
```

It works inside the same action and but when ever I am redirecting into some other controller ->action session doesn't display anything.

Can anyone help?

Comment: How do you put and get data from this object? Do you use save and get methods?

Comment: Yes we do save and get details like this.                              use Cygnite\Common\SessionManager\Session;                                use Cygnite\Common\Encrypt;                                    $session = new Session(new Encrypt); $session->save($key, $value); $session->get($key);

Comment: You should try using session property and check if there are those data using `var_dump(SESSION::session);`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you create in each controller new `Session` object. And it's quite possible you should create one Session object and inject it for example as constructor argument to other classes.

```
use Cygnite\Common\SessionManager\Session;
use Cygnite\Common\Encrypt;        

$session = new Session(new Encrypt);
$session->save('something', 'My data');

class A 
{
  private $session;

  public function __construct($session) {
      $this->session = $session;

      echo $this->sesssion->get('something'); // it should work

      $x = new Session(new Encrypt); 
      echo $x->get('something'); // possible it won't work
}
```

Comment: Ok as per your example, what if after setting session into one controller I am redirecting into some other controller->action. Will it work ? Because again it will create a new object of session. Right ?

Comment: I don't know it for sure. Have you tested above code? Is it work as it should? If yes, you should probably create globally session object and then pass it to all your controllers/classes

Comment: Not it doesn't work. Is this issue because of namespace ? any idea ?

Comment: But have you tried to run only this file adding of course autoloader at the beginning or require manually cygnite files? The first of them should work. If it doesn't I have no idea what's wrong